# Why is modx getResources and phpthumbof showing the same thumb nail for different resources?

Tags: modx-revolution, phpthumb, modx-getresources

I have a getResources call that shows 6 items on my homepage:

```
[[!getResources?
  &tpl=`homepageInventoryCellTpl`
  &parents=`4`
  &resources=`-33`
  &depth=`10`
  &limit=`6`
  &includeContent=`1`
  &includeTVs=`1`
  &processTVs=`0`
  &hideContainers=`1`
  &showHidden=`1`
  &debug=`0`
  &sortbyTV=`vehicleonhomepage`
  &sortDirTV=`DESC`
  ]]
```

it does work showing 6 thumbs [for vehicles] but it shows the same thumb for each vehicle!

The output tag looks like:

```
<img class="img-responsive" 
src="
[[!phpthumbof? 
&input=`[[!++gallery.files_url]][[!getgalleryAlbumCover? 
&id=`[[!+tv.vehiclegallery]]`]]` 
&options=`&w=300`
]]" 
/>
```

Note that nothing is cached [!]

- getResources does work correctly and returns six different images if I remove the phpthumbof bit
- I've cleared all the different caches several times
- [[!++gallery.files_url]] just returns the gallery path [/assets/gallery/]
- [[!getgalleryAlbumCover? &id=`[[!+tv.vehiclegallery]] returns the actual name of the album cover
- the /assets/components/gallery/cache/ directory is writable.

Why is it showing the same thumb for all 6 vehicles?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In the end I removed phpPhumbOf and installed pThumb and problem disapeared.